# How can i change the row 0f NumericMatrix type to IntegerVector in Rcpp?

Tags: rcpp

I define a `NumericMatrix` A in `Rcpp`.  The first column stores the row number(integer value).How can i change  the first column to a `IntegerVector` ?

Comment: Please include some code you tried, what you tried, what failed, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The `NumericMatrix` is also a `NumericVector` which cannot contain data of different type in its data blob.

Maybe what you need is to put the `IntegerVector` in `A.attr("somewhere")`.